# Testing my PSU, and GPU

Tags: installation, power-supply, gpu

Bit of a complicated situation people..

But my main question is my PC seems to be running on my psu but it has a problem with my graphics card.

It needs two six pins to run it.. The card runs on my friends PC .. Just has problems on mine .

To test it, can i hook the card up to my PC but use the two six pins from his PSU in his PC to provide power to it?

Or will it create a problem as it's an external source of power?

Comment: Should be fine but that's an awkward setup. What are the power outputs on each of the PSUs? The make and model of the PSUs and GPU in question?

Comment: Mines a 910watt and friends is a 500watt I just want to see if my PSU is the problem

Comment: Makes and models? They can make a huge difference.

Comment: My one is a silencer 910 watt not sure about his it's an older model psu but it does run the graphics card

Comment: Hmm... Without sitting in front of it, I have no idea. It is absolutely possible to run a system using multiple power supplies, though. They actually make adapters that fit on the motherboard power connector so you can run a PSU without attaching it to a full system (Good for Liquid cooling systems or making makeshift workbench power supplies for various purposes).

Comment: @NathanialMeek don't use the phrase "absolutely possible" it's unclear.  The common phrase for when something is impossible is to say it's "absolutely impossible".  Also you can do it with the green and black PSU mod,  i.e. just a paperclip in a second, without the need for an adaptor (I don't know whether adaptors are better in any way). He needs no adaptor  / green black mod, though if the external PSU is already on

Comment: You are probably clear enough, but pics may help, to clarify re 2 six pins. But anyhow, you won't harm anything by trying an external power supply from another computer to power the graphics card.

Comment: To be fair, if "absolutely impossible" is correct usage then the inverse must be as well. Here's a link to a PSU Jump Start Adapter.

https://www.frozencpu.com/products/5141/psu-218/FrozenCPU_24-pin_Power_Supply_Jump_Start_Connector.html?tl=g12c133s88